# Can you use linsolve on cells composed of matrices and vectors?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I need to make a matrix of matrices in Matlab to later be used when solving a system of linear equations.

I know one solution is to create a mxn cell, and fill each cell with a matrix or vector, but you can't use cells with linsolve(), so this won't help me.

How can I have a matrix of matrices in Matlab, or is there a way to use linsolve on cell data structure?

Thanks!

clarification:

I have one cell structure

```
    A =  [25x25 double]    [25x1 double]    [25x1 double]
         [ 1x25 double]    [          0]    [          0]
         [ 1x25 double]    [          0]    [          0]
```

and another

```
    b = [          0]
        [25x1 double]
        [          1]
```

And I want to do `linsolve(A, b)`. Is this possible?

Comment: See my answer. I hadn't looked at/thought about the contents of `A` and `b` yet, but many combinations of elements in `A` and `b` are **incompatible** (i.e., their matrix dimensions are not correct for the problem `A*x=b`). So...I'm at a loss. Can you clarify what you want to accomplish precisely?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do (which is probably the reason the function `linsolve` does not accept cells).

If you want to solve for *all* combinations between `A` and `b`, i.e., the systems

```
A{1,1}*x = b{1}   A{1,1}*x = b{2}   A{1,1}*x = b{3}
A{2,1}*x = b{1}   A{2,1}*x = b{2}   A{2,1}*x = b{3}
...               ...               ...
A{1,2}*x = b{1}   A{1,2}*x = b{2}   A{1,2}*x = b{3}
A{2,2}*x = b{1}   A{2,2}*x = b{2}   A{2,2}*x = b{3}
...               ...               ...
A{3,3}*x = b{1}   A{3,3}*x = b{2}   A{3,3}*x = b{3}
```

then you can do this by issuing

```
answers = cellfun(@(bb) ...
    cellfun(@(aa) linsolve(aa, bb), A, 'uni',false), ...
    b, 'uni',false)
```

If, on the other hand, you want to solve for each corresponding *row* of `A` and `b`, i.e., the systems

```
A{1,1}*x = b{1}   A{2,1}*x = b{2}   A{3,1}*x = b{3}
A{1,2}*x = b{1}   A{2,2}*x = b{2}   A{3,2}*x = b{3}
A{1,3}*x = b{1}   A{2,3}*x = b{2}   A{3,3}*x = b{3}
```

you can do that by issuing

```
answers = cell(3,1);
for ii = 1:3
    answers{ii} = ... 
        cellfun(@(aa) linsolve(aa, bb{ii}), A(ii,:), 'uni',false);
end
```

(if anyone sees how to vectorize that last one, please let me know :)